# Javascript syntax

Tags: javascript

How do you say `if (A == 0) OR (B == 0)`?

Comment: Jesus. The difference in complexity sure is big.

Comment: Compared to what? Prolog? Turtle? Cheese-strings? Quantum Chromodynamics?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if (A == 0 || B == 0)
```

or

```
if ((A == 0) || (B == 0))
```

Check out [Control Structures](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Control_Structures) and [Operators](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Operators) on Wikibooks

Answer (score 15):

Just to be snarky:

```
if (A === 0 || B === 0)
```

Comment: Now all you have to do is change your name from "Coehoorn" to "Coercion" ;)

Comment: Actually, that's a good point. Without the strict check for equality, all kinds of falsy values count as zero. If we're going to be lax, might as well just do if !(A && B)

Answer (score 8):

```
if (  A == 0  ||  B == 0 ) {
}
```

Comment: I've faced this dilemma before; what I did was give the best answer a checkmark (15pts) and the rest of them that were almost as good +1s.

Answer (score 6):

depends if you mean exclusive or inclusive OR :)

**Inclusive OR:**

```
if(A == 0 || B == 0) 
{ 
}
```

**Exclusive OR:**

```
if(A == 0 && B != 0 || A != 0 && B == 0) 
{ 
}
```

Comment: Actually a simpler xor can be achieved by if(!A != !B) but perhaps readability suffers. JS also has a native bitwise xor in ^ where that applies.

Comment: annakata: Why not (A != B). It will give the same truth table as (A==0 XOR B==0).